# Clustering or Grouping data by a variable of score to have a bar plot by counts of each group showing a descending exponential trend

Tags: python, grouping, cluster-analysis

I am conducting a simulation in Python where I generate 1000 scores ranging from 50 to 300. My goal is to group these scores into 8 ranges so that a bar plot of the count of each range, ranked from highest to lowest, displays an exponential descending trend. I am considering whether to use clustering methods or other grouping techniques to accomplish this task.